# Building/Running IOS 5.0 from xcode on 4.3.3 Device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am trying to run an application in xcode 4.2 to IPhone 4.3.3. All what I see to run against are:

```
IOS Device 
IPad 5 Simulator  
Iphone 5 Simulator
```

I tried to change my Code Signing, but still did not work. I am getting this message:

> ```
> "Xcode cannot run using the selected device.
>
> No provisioned IOS devices are available with compatible 
> IOS version. Connect an IOS device with a recent enough version 
> of the IOS to run your application or choose an IOS simulator 
> as the destination"
> ```

I already have the provisioning already setup successfully for my IPhone 4.3.3.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure your project has a deployment target of 4.3.3 or less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the Project's Target. Under the **Summary**, make sure the **Deployment Target** is set to the lowest version you want to support (4.0, 4.3.3, whichever you prefer).

Answer (score 1):

Look at **Deployment Target** Settings in Build Settings. Set it to 4.3

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your iOS deployment Target is set to iOS 4.3 or less